# Removing lowest level child recursively Symfony/Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm currently working with a data structure that uses nodes in a nodes table. It is self-referencing, in that it has an id and parent_id column. The parent-child relationship is a one-to-many. Meaning multiple nodes can have the same parent_id. This can also branch downwards in a variable number of levels.

The problem is that I can't just remove a parent, as that fails on a foreign key constraint. That's good, as I don't want the children to be orphaned. However it does mean that I have to recursively loop through the children until I get to the lowest level, remove that child, and then work back up.

I've had no luck so far. This is my "best" attempt, but the toRemove array always turns out to be empty when I dump it.

```
/**
 * @var array
 */
private $toRemove;

/**
 * constructor.
 *
 * @param array $toRemove
 */
public function __construct(
    EntityManagerInterface $entityManager,
    array $toRemove = []
)
{
    $this->toRemove = $toRemove;
}

someMainFunc(blabla)
{
    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
        $this->removeChildrenFromLowestLevelUp($node)
    }
    dump($this->toRemove);die;
}

public function removeChildrenFromLowestLevelUp(Node $node)
{
    if (null === $node->getChildren()) {
        // Node has no children, add to toRemove array
        $this->toRemove[] = $node;
    }

    /** @var Node $child */
    foreach ($node->getChildren() as $child) {
        $this->removeChildrenFromLowestLevelUp($child);
    }
}
```

I am aware there are a multitude of solutions for this on the internet, but I can't quite get any of them to do it in the way I want.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You don't wanna do that.

First of all, that means a lot of queries and in memory operations.
Second, that's a reinvention of wheel, as such mechanisms are already implemented in both databases and Doctrine.

You can do that at Doctrine level using `cascade:remove` option in mapping for this relationship.[Check documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/working-with-associations.html) for more details.

Just remember, that - as stated in documentation - all related object will be loaded from DB into memory and then removed. That also means some unnecessary queries.

Second way of achieving that is using SQL's `ON DELETE CASCADE`, which does a similar thing, but on the database level. You can set it in [Doctrine by using `onDelete=CASCADE`](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/working-with-objects.html) option in your mapping.

Basing on your description, I would recommend second option.

Comment: I am pretty convinced that it is exactly what I want to do. Cascading on both doctrine and database level doesn't work. I assume it's because the second it tries to cascade the first child, it notices that there's a reference to that child and it doesn't know what to do with that. If that's not the case, I don't know what's up. Either way, both these things were the first things I've tried with no success. I'm aware the approach I'm asking for is heavy, but that's not an issue. Thanks for your advice though.

Comment: I'll stay with my advice. Cascade deleting should work perfectly fine with such a multilevel tree structure. Maybe some other relation blocks the whole operation? How exactly "it doesn't work"? Any errors?

Comment: It's like I already said in my original post. It fails on a foreign key constraint, parent_id referencing id. Cascading is not doing it, which again is why I see no better alternative than to use this heavier approach.